# Cannot modify a specific CSS class in Firefox UI

Tags: css, firefox, customization

When using CSS to modify the dropdown list from the urlbar in Firefox, everything works as expected except for applying CSS to the `.ac-emphasize-text` class.

Changes to `.ac-emphasize-text` have no effect, and don't even show up in DOM Inspector.

To see a sample of text with this class, enable the Unified Toolbar (set `browser.urlbar.unifiedcomplete` to true, if it is not already) and then, in the urlbar, type in any keyword you have defined, followed by a space, and then more text.

Why can't this style be modified with a CSS overlay?

Answer (score 2):

I found your question a challenge... 
So, I played with it a little bit. 
'ac-emphisize-text' is in DOM. you have to descend a few elements from where shift+right-click will activate inspector.
Path to:

```
/* (panel) id PopupAutoCompleteRichResult > autocomplete-richlistbox > box-inherit scrollbox-innerbox > autocomplete-richlistitem > (ac-title-box) ac-url-box > ac-url > ac-normal-text ac-url-text > (span) ac-emphasize-text */
```

so, this is the best I can do, with the time I have.
In userChrome.css - start with this.

```
*|span.ac-emphasize-text {
color:orange !important;
border: 1px solid white !important;
}
```

It's not pretty, but I use 'odd' colors, bg, borders to make my changes stand out while tinker...

hope it helps.
Landis.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I will check it out.  I use odd colors while tinkering as well. :-)